Continuity of $e^f$, f being continuous
Suppose $f\in C(K)$ where K is compact Hausdorff space. Then how to show that $e^f$ is continuous on K?
I tried by the following way :
As f is continuous, so $f^2,f^3,...$ are all continuous. But how to show that the series $1+f+f^2/2! +f^3 /3! +...$ is convergent?

You can show that this series of functions converges locally uniformly (using that K is compact so bounded and using M-Test) and since all functions are continous then so is the limit.

composition of continuous function is continuous.

Hint.
$$
e^{f(x)}-e^{f(y)}=\big(f(x)-f(y)\big)e^\xi,
$$
where $\xi$ is a value between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$. Hence
$$
|e^{f(x)}-e^{f(y)}|\le M\big|f(x)-f(y)\big|,
$$
where
$$
M=e^{\max_{k\in K} f(x)}.
$$
